# why is a multi bound generic not checked at compile Time

Tags: java, generics, interface, extension-methods

suppose I have simple classes like this

```
public interface Something{
    public void doSomtehing()
}

class A{
    public int getAVal(){
        return 0;
    }
}

class AWithSomething extends A implements Something{
    public void doSomething{
        //in fact do nothing, HAHA
    }
}

abstract class B{
    public abstract <T extends A & Something> T getAWithSomething()
}

class C extends B{

    //allowed??? gives warnig about unchecked conversion
    public A getAWithSomething {
        return new A();
    }
}

class D extends B{

    //same unchecked warning
    public AWithSomething getAWithSomething(){
        return new AWithSomething();
    }
}

C c = new C();
//not implemented but seems valid
c.getAWithSomething().doSomething();

D d = new D();
d.getAWithSomething().doSomething();
```

So my main question is: Why does the compiler allow class `C` to return just an A without checking if it implements the interface at compile-time?

EDIT (due to comment from darijan):
hmm, but I'm NOT allowed to declare it like this:

```
class C extends B{

    //not allowed!
    public Something getAWithSomething {
        return new Something(){ 
            doSomething(){}
         };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JLS calls it [migration compatibility](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.7). Library implementors should be allowed to generify their APIs (`B`) without breaking clients (`C`). In fact, one could replace `B` with `List`, `getAWithSomething()` with `get(int)` and `C` with a custom `List`-implementation, such as apache commons `FixedSizeList`.

Type variables in method signatures are erased to a raw class or interface type. The type variable `T` in `B.getAWithSomething()` is erased to its left-most bound `A`. Migration compatibility is based on the resulting method signature `A getAWithSomething()`. That means subclasses overriding `getAWithSomething()` must declare a return type of `A` or a subtype of thereof.

Do note that you get a warning saying "careful, you're passing an `A` off as an `A&Something`, this could go wrong". And it could: Calling `doSomething()` on the returned `A` will throw a `ClassCastException`, because `A` can't be cast to `Something`.

Comment: shure? mustn't it be at least an `A`, or must it only have ALL methods from `A`? And if this is true, why it mustn't also have all methods from `something`? If the Api from `B` gets a `C` object and trys to call `doSomething()` on it, it will break. Is this really intendet?

Comment: @RafaelT Hopefully all your additional questions are adressed now.

Comment: so I can read your answer as 'multiple bounded generic return types are completely useless (at least by now), because they are ensuring nothing and implementer is free to break it'??

Comment: @RafaelT One could look at it that way. The implementor is free to break the type contract. However, were the compiler to enforce the type contract, implementors could still break the contract by infinitely looping, throwing an exception, etc. Most implementors don't do that though.

Comment: shure. but if implementor loops infinity, I'll never get a return and thus HE breaks the code. I already hear the complaints about a non Idiot aware API that I build...

Comment: @RafaelT I would argue that it's also the implementor breaking code when he knowingly ignores or suppresses compiler warnings. And he would have to in this case. If you choose to disagree, Java generics (and probably Java as a whole) are not for you.

Comment: hmm, one may argue like that - as I would do it too. But about the 'generic isn't for you', I don't quite think so. As Example take `ArrayList<String>`. No one can add `Apple` Objects to it (at least in Eclipse), no matter what compiler supressions one likes to set. The generic `String` ensures at compile-time that only Strings or subclasses (which doesn't exist in this example) are added. Even list.add((String)apple) isn't allowed by the compiler... Just wondering, why it isn't like this in multi-bounded closures